# Retrieving shopify Shop object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I feel like I'm missing something extremely simple here. So i have the authentication session, and I essentially want to load the current Shop object to access somethings, like the email address, shop_owner, etc. How can I retrieve that to essentially get this response?

```
http://api.shopify.com/shop.html#show
```

I tried looking at /admin/shop.json and using

```
ShopifyAPI::Shop.find(someidnumber)
```

but no go?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The endpoint is `/admin/shop.json`. If you're using the ShopifyAPI gem, in `resources/shop.rb` you'll see there is a `current` function.

Calling `ShopifyAPI::Shop.current` will return a Shop object with the details you're looking for.

If you're not getting the correct object/response back then you must not be authenticated properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can access it with

```
ShopifyAPI::Shop.current
```

However, in order for it to work - you need your controller to inherit from `ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController`

Something like:

```
class MyController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
```

Comment: That means I will not have access to my own ApplicationController. And will this work in this case? ApplicationHelper in turns won't be available too on MyController

Comment: And another problem with this is that my controller kept requesting for /login page.

Comment: This works assuming it is a merchant facing controller/view and they are already logged in. Otherwise you'll have to pass them through the home/splash page controller to get authenticated first.